# MongoDB Remote connection with php

Tags: php, mongodb

Deployed a quick cloud server just to host a MongoDB to tinker with it out of curiosity. It's installed and works. Made a test DB/Table like this:

```
 db.items.insert({ name: 'eggs', quantity: 10, price: 1.50 })
 db.items.insert({ name: 'bacon', quantity: 3, price: 3.50 })
 db.items.insert({ name: 'tomatoes', quantity: 30, price: 0.50 })
```

When I run `db.items.find({})` all the items appear and all is well.

Now in PHP when I connect to that database from a different server I do this:

```
  // open connection to MongoDB server
  $conn = new Mongo('mongodb://theAdmin:Gold1234@165.225.130.252:27017');

  // access database
  $db = $conn->test;

  // access collection
  $collection = $db->items;

  // execute query
  // retrieve all documents
  $cursor = $collection->find();

  // iterate through the result set
  // print each document
  echo $cursor->count() . ' document(s) found. <br/>';  
  foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $obj['name'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Quantity: ' . $obj['quantity'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Price: ' . $obj['price'] . '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
  }
```

and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'Failed to connect to: 165.225.130.252:27017: Transport
>   endpoint is not connected' in /home/moosex/public_html/info.php:4
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/moosex/public_html/info.php(4):
>   Mongo->__construct('mongodb://[theA...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/moosex/public_html/info.php on line 4

I've looked up and tried several different ways to connect and still can't get it. How am I supposed to connect remotely?

BTW, that is the actual username password and address to that server(there's nothing on there except for eggs bacon and tomatoes), if you can connect to it, god bless you lol.

Comment: Firewall blocking traffic on 27017?

Comment: trying to view this conf file, just having a hard time. here's the documentation for the server: http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/jpc2/Joyent+MongoDB+SmartMachine

Comment: the only text editor this machine has is vim which I haven't used in a very long time. trying to remember how to open the mongodb.conf lol

Comment: Ok the mongodb.conf has a bind_ip of 127.0.0.1 should I change that? or is that dumb?

Comment: ok i changed that to the remote server's IP... still the same issue

Comment: comment out the bind_ip with a `#` and then restart mongodb

Comment: I tryed changing it to 0.0.0.0, restarted mongo and still same issue.

Comment: Ok trying to comment it out now

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is localhost for the config, that means only your computer will be able to connect

Comment: just commented out and restarted, same issue :(

Comment: As @Phil Said have you checked that the firewall connected to the server actually allows traffic on 27017?

Comment: Yeah, no firewall on this server

Comment: Ok I know you said that is the right user and pw but try starting mongodb without auth and stake out the auth string from the connection string, what do you get?

Comment: @Sammaye I did this and it worked: 
$connection = new Mongo('mongodb://theAdmin:Gold1234@192.81.208.87/test'); please post this as the answer so I can give you the credit. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think you deserve the marks there, hmm weird that taking out the port works with the auth. Maybe something with the parser there, but yea try to use the MongoClient class instead of Mongo if you have the latest driver since MongoClient is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to debug "random weirdness" like this, it is very useful to turn on the internal driver logging.
The driver does whole lot of things behind the scenes, and can spit out all sort of important debug information.

Add the following at the top of your script:

```
<?php
MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::ALL);
?>
```

By default the logger will spew out "php error messages" (E_NOTICE/E_WARNING), if you have error_log enabled, make sure to check that file for the results.

For your (slightly modified) connection string, I get the following results

```
Notice: PARSE   INFO: Parsing mongodb://theAdmin:Gold1234@localhost:27027 in Command line code on line 1
Notice: PARSE   INFO: - Found user 'theAdmin' and a password in Command line code on line 1
Notice: PARSE   INFO: - Found node: localhost:27027 in Command line code on line 1
Notice: PARSE   INFO: - Connection type: STANDALONE in Command line code on line 1
Notice: PARSE   INFO: - No database name found for an authenticated connection. Using 'admin' as default database in Command line code on line 1
Notice: CON     INFO: mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a STANDALONE connection in Command line code on line 1
Notice: CON     INFO: connection_create: creating new connection for localhost:27027 in Command line code on line 1
Notice: CON     WARN: connection_create: error while creating connection for localhost:27027: Invalid argument in Command line code on line 1
Notice: CON     WARN: Couldn't connect to 'localhost:27027': Invalid argument in Command line code on line 1
```

I suspect a firewall issue at either end.. Can you connect to the server using the mongo shell?

Comment: It was 100% the server. I was using a cloud machine from joyent, it was terrible. I had this up and running in 15 minutes by using an ubuntu cloud machine from digital ocean. Dude, I was looking everywhere on decent documentation on getting an error log in PHP from mongo, thanks so much for this.