# How to connect mongodb using PHP remotely?

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection

Please find below my code to connect Mongodb remotely.

```
$r=new MongoClient("mongodb://db_name:db_pass@192.168.1.1:27017");
```

But i couldn't connect to database.

Let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error/output that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this one helps for you from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546860/mongodb-remote-connection-with-php)
Add the following at the top of your script:

```
<?php
MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Yes. i already set this but getting issue. MongoLog not found like this.

Comment: did you check is this port(27017) is open or not ?

Comment: Yes. it's open.But still getting same issue. Issue is "MongoClient" class not found.

Comment: did you add extension=mongo.so in php.ini ?
Once you add please restart your apache/httpd service

Comment: Yes. i have added it. it's working fine. But it doesn't working for lampp. It's working for ubuntu default apache2.